# multiprocessing launch from within module or class, not from main()

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to use Python's multiprocessing unit to make effective use of multiple cpu's to speed up my processing.

All seems to work, however I want to run `Pool.map(f, [item, item])` from within a class, in a sub module somewhere deep in my program. The reason is that the program has to prepare the data first and wait for certain events to happen before there is anything to be processed.

The [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) says you can only run from within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement. I don't understand the significance of that and tried it anyway, like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Foo(object):
  n = 1000000
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x + 1
    pass

  def run(self):
    for i in range(1,self.n):
      self.x *= 1.0*i/self.x
    return self

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def go_all(self):
        work = [Foo(i) for i in range(960)]
        def do(obj):
            return obj.run()

        p = Pool(16)
        finished_work = p.map(do, work)
        return

bar = Bar()
bar.go_all()
```

It indeed doesn't work! I get the following error:

> PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup
>   **builtin**.function failed

I don't quite understand why as everything seems to be perfectly pickeable. I have the following questions:

1. Can this be made to work without putting the p.map line in my main program?
2. If not, can "main" programs be called as sub-routines/modules, such to make it still work?
3. Is there some handy trick to loop back from a submodule to the main program and run it from there?

I'm on Linux and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood the documentation. What the documentation says is to do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar = Bar()
    bar.go_all()
```

So your `p.map` line does *not* need to be inside your "main function", or whatever. Only the code that actually spawns the subprocesses has to be "guarded". This is **unavoidable due to limitations of the Windows OS**.

Moreover, the function that you pass to `Pool.map` has to be importable (functions are pickled simply by their names, the interpreter then has to be able to import them to rebuild the function object when they are passed to the subprocess). So you should probably move your `do` function at the global level to avoid pickling errors.

Comment: Do you mean the global level of this module or all the way to the main module? The latter would be very inconvenient.

Comment: On the global level within the submodule works! Not that I understand it,.. but it's good for now.

Comment: @Bastiaan If you have a module `a` that defines a function `def g(): def f(): ...` how can you import `f` from `a`? **You cannot**. On windows, due to fundamental limitations of windows, that is what python will do when executing the callback passed to `p.map`! The function is "pickled" *by name*, then sent to the subprocess. The subprocess hence receives only the name of the function and the module where it is defined and imports it, and then performs the real call and sends back the result. But for this to work the callback has to be importable.

Answer (score 1):

The extra restrictions on the `multiprocessing` module on ms-windows stem from the fact that it doesn't have the `fork` system call. On UNIX-like operating systems, `fork` makes a *perfect copy* of a process and continues to run that next to the parent process. The only difference between them is that `fork` returns different value in the parent and child processes.

On ms-windows, `multiprocessing` needs to start a new Python instance using a native method to start processes. Then it needs to bring that Python instance into the same state as the "parent" process.

This means (among other things) that the Python code must be *importable* without side effects like trying to start yet another process. Hence the use of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.

Comment: I'm on Linux, are you saying it doesn't need to be in the main in that case?

Comment: @Bastiaan Yes, linux has `fork` which avoids having to re-import the main module. You can test it by simply writing an example script `from multiprocessing import Pool; def f(x): return x+1; p = Pool(); print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))` (add the importsOn linux it works fine printing `[2,3,4]` on Windows it raises an exception).

Comment: It depends. By default on Linux the `fork` method of starting a process is used. This does not have the extra restrictions that apply to ms-windows. But if you use the *forkserver* start method, you have the same restrictions w.r.t. importability. Consult the `multiprocessing` documentation for all the ins and outs.